# Can a coroutine yield values in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, pipeline, coroutine

So I understand how `generators` and `coroutines` work. Broadly speaking, `generators` produce data and `coroutines` consume data. Now, what I am trying to do is combine both these features.

I have defined a `coroutine` that receives a `list` as an input and then tries to `**yield**` items from the list one at a time, like a `generator` would do.

Here is my code -

```
def coroutine():
    print('Starting coroutine')
    value = (yield)
    for i in value:
        yield i



c=coroutine()
c.__next__()
c.send([1,2,3,4,5])


for val in c:
    print(val)
```

The problem is, the first list item is being lost. The **`value 1`** is not being returned from the coroutine.

Based on my understanding, the flow should have been as follows.

1. `c=coroutine()` ----> Declares the `coroutine` without starting it.
2. `c.__next__()`  ----> This starts the `coroutine` and it advances to the line -  `value = (yield)` and stops there.
3. `c.send([1,2,3,4,5])`  ----> This passes the new `list` to the waiting coroutine i.e `value = (yield)`. The coroutine now proceeds to the next **`yield`** statement inside the for loop.
4. The **for loop** in the main program is supposed to receive each items of the list that it initially passed. But this does not happen.

Can you please explain why ? The reason I am trying to do this is to generate a **pipeline**. Each component will receive items, modify it and then yield it to the next coroutine in the pipeline.

Please help.

**EDIT --------------------**

The output is as follows -

```
Starting coroutine
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing that when calling to `send`, the corrutine will go till the next `yield` and that one will be called, so, if you do :

```
c=coroutine()
c.__next__()
print(c.send([1,2,3,4,5]))


for val in c:
    print(val)
```

You will see how the missing value is printed (as it is yielded in the `send` call)

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/UnrulyOddRelationaldatabase)

For the behaviour you desire you can add an extra `yield` statement to the corrutine:

```
def coroutine():
    print('Starting coroutine')
    value = (yield)
    yield
    for i in value:
        yield i
```

Comment: Why should it work this way ? Doesnt the second yield statement wait till the value is requested for in the calling function ? c.send(..) should just advance the coroutine to the next yield statement and it'll wait there till it is called. I am asking this because thats what happens in generators, right ?

Comment: @BoudhayanDev, corrutines execution pauses when the arrive to a yield clause. Also it is not the same a yield that gets a value that a yield that returns it. This is just how they work in python. You can always include an extra yield, to wait for the next calls in the iterations, and get the behaviour you desire.

Comment: So, what you are saying is, a yield that is supposed to return value will be executed and then the coroutine/generator pauses and NOT the other way round, i.e the coroutine/generator pauses once it encounters the returning yield without executing it ?

Comment: The corrutine will always pause once it arrives a `yield`, but in a `yield` that returns something will advance when calling to `next`, the ones that are waiting for some value will advance when calling to `send`

Comment: I understood the difference between the next and send method and also receiving yields and the returning ones. What I am trying to understand is that whether the PAUSING occurs after executing the returning yield statement or it happens before executing the returning yield ( in this case assumption is that the execution takes place once the generator's value is fetched ) ???

Comment: @BoudhayanDev So, first yield (waits for a value) -> call send -> advance until next yield (where corrutine will wait again) `yield i` so it yields that value, next iteration advance until next yield, which is the next `yield i` and so on. So, YES, the execution takes place once the value is fetched ofc.